# document.getelementbyid always returns null in angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component like this

```
export class NotificationPostComponent extends PostComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    commentsDto: IComment[] = [];
    commentId = '';
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data=>{
      this.post = data.post;
    });
    this.route.params.subscribe((param : Params) => {
      const slug = param['slug'];      
      this.commentId = param['commentid'];
      this.notifiService.loadCommentsOfPost(slug, this.commentId).subscribe(data=>{
          this.commentsDto = data.comments;       
        })       
    });
    super.ngOnInit();    
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    var idDiv = document.getElementById(this.commentId)
    console.log(idDiv)
  }
}
```

This is a html with id is Guid:

```
<div id="{{cmt.id}}" *ngFor="let cmt of commentsDto">
  <div>comment</div>
</div>
```

the problem is that after view is initialized its document.getElementById is always null.
Please tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: That what happens when you copy snippets from different source without analysing throughout

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `document.getElementById` you can use Angular's built-in API: [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren).

Then, the inline Template could be extracted into a new component.

**Template**

```html
<button (click)="scrollToBottom()">Scroll to last comment</button>

<app-comment [title]="comment.title" *ngFor="let comment of comments$ | async">
</app-comment>

<button (click)="scrollToTop()">Scroll to 1st Comment</button>
```

In the Component, use *ViewChildren* to access the collection of your *CommentComponents* represented by a [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList).

If you need to access the HTML-Element directly, you need to configure @ViewChildren to read the ElementRefence (`@ViewChildren(CommentComponent, { read: ElementRef })`).

**Component**

```js
export class NotificationPostComponent extends PostComponent
  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    comments$ = /* Stream of Comments */

    @ViewChildren(CommentComponent, { read: ElementRef })
  commentElementReferences: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLElement>> | undefined;
}
```

Next, if you need to scroll to a specific element by a ID or something like that, you can mark each Comment Component with an `attr-Binding`.

**Template**

```html
<app-comment
  [title]="comment.title"
  [attr.data-anchor]="comment.id"
  *ngFor="let comment of comments$ | async"
>
</app-comment>
```

Now, you can add some logic to your component finding the Element you need, allowing you to scroll to it.

**Component**

```js
private scrollToCommentById(id: string) {
    if (!this.commentElementReferences) return;

    const commentToScrollTo = this.commentElementReferences
      .map((reference) => reference.nativeElement)
      .find((element) => element.getAttribute('data-anchor') === id);

    commentToScrollTo.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
```

Finally, you can connect to the activated route, triggering your scrolling mechanism when navigation kicks in.

```js
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Listen to parameter changes in route
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap
      .pipe(
        map((paramMap) => paramMap.get('id')),
        filter((id) => !!id),
        tap((id) => this.scrollToCommentById(id))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

**Demo**

**[This StackBlitz @ViewChild Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sz8yf3?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)** shows how everything can be set up. There you also see how the button is set up that scrolls to a specific Comment by its ID.

Comment: when you has a serie of elements use ViewChildren -ViewChild only get the first one. @NamNgyen, try to reach the element inside subscribe function enclosed all in a setTimeout: `subscribe(res=>{this.commentsDto = data.comments;setTimeout(()=>{const el=document.getElementById(...)}))`

Comment: I recommend not using setTimeout, since it causes a new ChangeDetection-Cycle. It is possible without setTimeout. I updated my example to show how to deal with a collection of elements. Thanks for the hint. I missed the point that all Comments should be accessed.

Comment: I want when my component is loaded. It will scroll to element with specify ID.
Document.getElementById (this.commentID) .crollintoView ({
         Behavior: "Smooth",
         Block: "Start",
         inline: "Nearest"
       });
How to do this with @viewchildren

Comment: @GregorWoiwode, you need "wait" Angular render. There're three options: setTimeout, ChangeDetectorRef or, in this case, subscribing to QueryList.changes

Comment: Hi, I updated the Demo showing how to connect ActivatedRoute with Comment-Scrolling: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sz8yf3?file=src/app/comment-list/comment-list.component.ts

Comment: I want to emphasize setTimeout is no option. I agree, there are situations forcing us to trigger ChangeDetection manually. Therefore, we can use the ChangeDetectorRef-Service provided by Angular. Each time we think setTimeout is an option, we need to take a breath, step back and take a look at our Code-Design.

Comment: @Eliseo, sorry I missed your last comment.
You can take a look at StackBlitz. There is no need to write extra code waiting for Angular to render, since we have a life-cycle-hook for that.: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sz8yf3?file=src/app/comment-list/comment-list.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--see the tempalte reference variable "#comment"-->
<div #comment id="{{cmt.id}}" *ngFor="let cmt of commentsDto">
  <div>comment</div>
</div>

//In commentsyou has the "QueryList" (an specie of array)
@ViewChildren('comment') comments:QueryList<ElementRef>

this.notifiService.loadCommentsOfPost(slug, this.commentId).subscribe(data=>{
      this.commentsDto = data.comments;       
      //you neeed wait Angular "render" the elements
      setTimeout(()=>{
        const comment=this.comments
            .find(x=>x.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')==myId)
        if (comment)
            comment.nativeElement.scrollIntoView(
              {Behaivor:"Smooth",Block:Start,inline:"Nearest"})
       })
    })
```

Well, you can find using "nativeElement.getAttribute" or find the index of the comment and find the element at this index. some like

```
        const index=this.commentsDto.findIndex(x=>x.id==myInd)
        const comment=this.comments
            .find((_,i)=>i==index)
```